# Super massive Black Hole and photon reduction

Tags: visible-light, black-holes, magnetic-fields, field-theory, photoelectric-effect

This is a picture of 2 galaxies taken from The Hubble. The arrow shows a smaller galaxy's black hole starving of the usual stars because of the binary rotation about the bigger galaxy that  is pulling stars away from it. Notice the ball of light are around the smaller one. Is the release of photons happening before the photon sphere? Are photons absorbed by atoms compressed out by gravity before the electrons are lost from the atom?

[image]
http://chandra.harvard.edu/press/16_releases/press_010616.html

[image]

Comment: 1. Have a look at [how to write good question titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6413/50583). 2. It's not particularly clear what your actual question is. What do you mean by "photons are shedding around the smaller one"? What is actually depicted in your photo? And I cannot parse your last sentence, please try to rephrase it into proper English.

Comment: Besides the ridiculous title, I think that this could be an interesting question if cleaned up a bit.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Better?

Comment: The title is still very vague about what the content of the question is - and why don't you get rid of the ridiculous "Show me your hole"? You still aren't even telling us what exactly is seen in the picture (which black hole is this? What exactly are we seeing?`), and it is still unclear what you mean by *"Are photons absorbed by atoms compressed out buy gravity before the electrons are lost from the atom"*. Do you mean *by* instead of *buy*? Why are the electrons "lost" and what does "compressed out" mean?

Comment: If it was a neutron star atoms would loss its electrons and protons before coming a part of that star, its the same with a black hole.

Comment: You asked me in the question where you blew 250 of your reputation on how to improve your questions: I saw that on a number of them you get the link on how to write a question. This one to start with will be improved with a link to the original article from where you took the picture. In general, links that support the framework of a question will be looked at before people complain. It is also advisable when copying pictures to copy the description from the original source. In the picture above the interpretation is not clear.

Comment: I have edited your question and answered it. The use of less striking words is advisable in asking elementary questions. Also a google search . For example  reading the "black hole" article in wikipedia, would tell you about the accretion disk .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Notice the photons are reduced around the smaller one. Is that happening before the photon sphere?

The [photon sphere](http://Notice%20the%20photons%20are%20reduced%20around%20the%20smaller%20one.%20Is%20that%20happening%20before%20the%20photon%20sphere?%20Are%20photons%20absorbed%20by%20atoms%20compressed%20out%20by%20gravity%20before%20the%20electrons%20are%20lost%20from%20the%20atom?) by definition does not send any photons in our direction, as it is

> a spherical region of space where gravity is strong enough that photons are forced to travel in orbits.

So the photons seen come from the region before, considering the dimensions of the system, light years  before.

> Are photons absorbed by atoms compressed out by gravity before the electrons are lost from the atom?

The photons seen in the picture are radiation  from the acceleration of ions  electrons and eventually protons as they fall in the black holes as well as the process seen in [accretion disks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accretion_disk)

> Gravitational and frictional forces compress and raise the temperature of the material causing the emission of electromagnetic radiation.

As the two black holes have to share the mass between them, (the larger one getting more), there are less in-falling  charged particles  to generate photons in the region between the two holes.

Answer (score 3):

In a comment you say (I fixed a few words in this quote) "If it was a neutron star an atom would lose its electrons and protons before becoming a part of that star"... And in the question you say, "Are photons absorbed by atoms compressed out by gravity".

This reminds me of Feynman's father. If you Google "feynman father photon", you should find the story of how Feynman's father thought that the photon that an atom emits, was already in the atom before it was emitted. According to the story, Feynman said no, it's not, but then he couldn't explain the way it actually works.

In this case, I think the simplest way to think about it, is that the electromagnetic field is everywhere, and a photon is an excitation of the electromagnetic field that carries energy. And so when an atom absorbs a photon, what happens is that the energy in the photon is transferred to the atom, and the photon no longer exists. And when an atom emits a photon, energy in the atom is being transferred to the local part of the electromagnetic field, creating a photon.

Also, a neutron star isn't created by the atoms of the collapsing star losing their protons and electrons. The protons actually turn into neutrons too (this involves the quarks) and the electrons turn into neutrinos and escape into space:

[What happens to Protons and Electrons when a Neutron star forms?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149648/what-happens-to-protons-and-electrons-when-a-neutron-star-forms)