# Statistical argument for n/p ratio in relativistic neutrino environment?

Tags: particle-physics, astronomy, neutrinos, neutrons

Consider a system with high-energy neutrinos (higher than rest mass energies of protons & neutrons) where the energy of a neutrino is specified as $E = p + sB$, $p$ being the magnitude of the momentum and $s$ its spin. $B$ is a constant external magnetic field.

I need to show using 'simple statistical mechanics' that the number density of neutrons is expected to be higher than that of protons.

I am aware that the situation is akin to a white dwarf/neutron star, and from [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149648/what-happens-to-protons-and-electrons-when-a-neutron-star-forms) I know that the electron degeneracy makes it energetically favorable for an *electron capture* process:

$$p+e→n+\nu_e$$

I think the 'simple statistical mechanics' that I need to use is the two-level occupation ratio:

$$ \frac{n}{p} = exp(-\frac{\Delta E}{kT}) $$

but how does one go from the information given to me to being able to apply the above?

**Edit:** After some more reading, I realize that I can relate $E_F$ to number densities. Assuming degenerate electron gas, which terms in the conservation laws can I relate to their Fermi energies and thus invoke the relationship to their respective number densities?

I am mildly certain electron energy/momentum terms can be replaced with their Fermi values due to the neutron star being a degenerate electron gas scenario. What else am I missing?

Comment: You seem to be confusing neutrinos and neutrons in places here.  Neutrinos have no magnetic moment.

Comment: You raise a fair point, but that is verbatim how the question was posed to me.

Comment: What can you assume as the density of the environment, since that matters? I'm also not following how you produce neutrinos with more energy than the nucleons?

Comment: Mass density? I can take it to be of the order of neutron star density, 10^17 kg/m^3.

Comment: I reckon that the assumption being made was of ultrarelativistic neutrinos. Verbatim, the assumption I was told to make was "(higher than rest mass energies of protons & neutrons)".